# error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'p'

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am facing this issue while running the task in Visual studio code. Here is the screen shot for reference.

[image]

here is the code for **tasks.json**

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

and code for **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

and code for **systemjs.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
      'common',
      'compiler',
      'core',
      'http',
      'platform-browser',
      'platform-browser-dynamic',
      'router',
      'router-deprecated',
      'upgrade',
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    };
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Please help me in resolving this issue i have no idea what i did wrong.

Comment: You could remove that `tsc` task at all, leave the file empty. And then open a  `cmd` and run `tsc` from there

Comment: I have the same issue, any solution found?

Comment: no i created whole thing from scratch

Answer (score 6):

seairth is correct,

you can run `tsc --version` to see if it is the new version of tsc you just installed, or `tsc --help` to see if -p is the supported option, e.g. I've installed a new version `2.5.2`, but when I run `tsc --version`, it always report `1.0.3`

it should be caused by path conflicting, delete the tsc path in Microsoft SDK from PATH environment, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running an older version of TypeScript that was installed with another package, such as the *Microsoft SDK*.  Bring up a console and execute `tsc`.  Make sure it is the version you are expecting it to be.  If not, then you will need to correct your `path` environment variable to ensure that the correct version is found first.